# When to split code into files/modules?

Tags: python, file, module, project

To date I had been developing only small Python scripts. They were not longer than 500 lines per each. Now I'm going to write something bigger - I think it will have about 1000 lines. Is it good idea to handle it in one file or is it good time to organize code in subdirectories?  I found some advices on how to modularize code, but I can't find any information about when to do that (or rather when it isn't waste of time).

Comment: I generally opt for separation of concerns. Get similar tasks together, like fetching data from db, performing date operations. Make these general enough to be used in your next project.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I usually do it under these circumstances:

- You could run parts of the application on thir own and running them would be useful (so they could be reused)
- A part of the application is abstract and the rest is concrete (The abstract parts could be reused)
- I want to divide it into 'plugins'
- A single script would get insanely large (then I divide e.g. by class or put the unittests into a separate file).

In general I try to go for reusability. If I cannot divide it into reusable parts I don't divide except it would get too large.

Comment: +1, good answer. only unittests _always_ belong in their own file imho.

Comment: And what do you mean by "insanely large"? Is 1000 lines enough?

Comment: @ciembor - I think "insanely large" pretty much just means "large enough that it gets annoying for you to navigate", which depends on personal preference. For me, the number of lines isn't really a good measure, since I keep everything folded anyway, but if a file ends up with, say, over 15-20 top-level classes/functions, I start considering splitting it up.